Fourier transform of indeterminate measure
Consider the following probability measure
$d\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{-1}\exp\Bigl(-(\ln{x})^2/2\Bigl)\chi_{(0,+\infty)}(x)$
whose moments are given by
$\mu_n = e^{n^2/2}$.
As discovered by Stieltjes the moment problem for this probability measure is indeterminate.
We can consider a new probability measure
$d\mu_c(x) = (1+csin(2\pi \ln x)d\mu(x)$
with $c \in [-1,1]$ which has the same moments as $d\mu(x)$.
By uniqueness of the Fourier transform, the measures $d\mu(x)$ and $d\mu_{c}(x)$ ($c \neq 0$) should have different characteristic functions. However, these characteristic functions should have the same Taylor expansion near the origin (since the moments are the same).
How to reconcile these two facts? The only way out seems to have some non-pertubative functions like $exp(-1/x^2)$.
